# Enlarge the exponent in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I want to make my math look big and easy to read like this:
[image]

Right now i looks like this, but the small font makes it extremely clumsy and hard to read when the document is zoomed out.
[image]

The code looks like this:

```
$$\text{solve}\left(10^{0.78478 \cdot\left(\log \left(\frac{m}{173.961}\right)\right)^{2}}=1.2,m\right)$$
```

Comment: Use `\displaystyle` inside the first `^`.

Comment: Using `\tfrac` makes it readable. Unrelated: don't use  the plain TeX construct `$$ ... $$` for displayed equations, use `\[ ... \]` instead.

Comment: of your two images, the black one is a lot easier to read than the blue, the wildly varying vertical displacement makes it very hard to scan across the expression and see the relationships between the parts

Comment: I'd replace `\cdot` with `\times`. According to [ISO 80000-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-1): "*If the point is used as the decimal sign, the cross and not the half-high dot should be used as the multiplication sign between numbers expressed with digits*". And I also agree that the second expression (in black) look miles better.

Comment: @Sigur - Thank you! However, when i do `\displaystyle` a "blank" line is created underneath the rest of the equation, which makes the brackets unnecessarily large. Image: https://gyazo.com/1d04cef9d9ae86cd2aceb94de9aef775
Is there any way to avoid this? :)

Comment: @Bernard - Thank you, looks great! Do you care to explain the advantage of using `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`?

Comment: `$$` is not supported latex syntax at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I agree, however, to capture an image of the black equation, i had to greatly zoom in, which would make the document unpleasant to read.

Comment: @Nikolai well you could put `\huge` before the display and it would be bigger.

Comment: @andselisk - Thank you for the feedback. The math i'm doing is of low difficulty, which means that my math teacher won't mind the slight error :) Appreciate it though!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Oh, i didn't know that, i'll remember that in the future. About adding `\huge`, would you mind typing out the entire equation with what you mean? :)

Comment: you have not provided a test document, but if you have `$$\textrm...$$` and it is too small then  `\huge $$\textrm...$$` will be bigger

Comment: ouch one of the reasons why the black image is so much more readable than the blue is the weird offset parenthesis in the blue version, and you now asked a new question specifically how to achieve that in TeX :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clarified in comments it seems that the main concern is that all the text is too small to read the math. Math follows the same size commands as text, although the size change command has to be outside the math. In this case `\Large` is the largest size that fits in the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
normal
\[
\operatorname{solve}
\bigl(10^{0.78478 \cdot
(\log \frac{m}{173.961})^{2}}
=1.2,m\bigr) \triangleright m=83.7164
\]

bigger fraction
\[
\operatorname{solve}
\bigl(10^{0.78478 \cdot
\bigl(\log \tfrac{m}{173.961}\bigr)^{2}}
=1.2,m\bigr) \triangleright m=83.7164
\]


\Large
of if you need bigger text

normal
\[
\operatorname{solve}
\bigl(10^{0.78478 \cdot
(\log \frac{m}{173.961})^{2}}
=1.2,m\bigr) \triangleright m=83.7164
\]

bigger fraction
\[
\operatorname{solve}
\bigl(10^{0.78478 \cdot
\bigl(\log \tfrac{m}{173.961}\bigr)^{2}}
=1.2,m\bigr) \triangleright m=83.7164
\]


\end{document}
```